# How do you overcome the "RuntimeError: Gamma ramp size is reported as 0." without changing the window type when using psychopy?

Tags: pygame, driver, glfw, pyglet, psychopy

I have developed a program to play videos in `psychopy` using a machine with Ubuntu 16.04, a NVIDIA GPU and associated driver. The program works perfectly fine on this machine. The program is rather large but of note, it uses `visual.Window(fullscr=True)` which as default uses the `pyglet` backend and also uses `visual.MovieStim3`. I am now trying to run this program on a different machine with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and integrated intel graphics (HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)) and am having problems.
new machine driver info below:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Here is the traceback when I run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/experiments/video_sorting/video_sorting.py", line 456, in <module>
    start_sorting(av_original_csv, user, usr_csv, bonus, last_video)
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/experiments/video_sorting/video_sorting.py", line 357, in start_sorting
    win = visual.Window(fullscr=True)
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/.conda/envs/conda_psychopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psychopy/visual/window.py", line 375, in __init__
    self.backend = backends.getBackend(win=self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/.conda/envs/conda_psychopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psychopy/visual/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in getBackend
    return Backend(win, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/.conda/envs/conda_psychopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psychopy/visual/backends/pygletbackend.py", line 227, in __init__
    self._origGammaRamp = self.getGammaRamp()
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/.conda/envs/conda_psychopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psychopy/visual/backends/pygletbackend.py", line 326, in getGammaRamp
    return getGammaRamp(self.screenID, self.xDisplay)
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/.conda/envs/conda_psychopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psychopy/visual/backends/gamma.py", line 120, in getGammaRamp
    rampSize = getGammaRampSize(screenID, xDisplay=xDisplay)
  File "/home/adf/mxj719/.conda/envs/conda_psychopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psychopy/visual/backends/gamma.py", line 285, in getGammaRampSize
    raise RuntimeError("Gamma ramp size is reported as 0.")
RuntimeError: Gamma ramp size is reported as 0.
Segmentation fault
```

This is a common problem it seems:
https://discourse.psychopy.org/t/gamma-problem-in-v1-90-2/4549

But each solution involves either switching the `visual.Window` type to `pygame` (which is now archaic for `psychopy`) or `glfw` (which is not a simple setup and is very new and not well documented). I would like a solution that allows me to continue using `pyglet`.

Another solution given involves ensuring that `xf86-video-intel` is installed to give a sensible LUT size, I have tried this and it seems that this driver is installed as default on Ubuntu 18, so this does not work for me.

Someone else mentions that I could comment out the `RuntimeError` in the source code but I could not find those lines of code where they pointed it out. (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psychopy/visual/backends/gamma.py).

Please also note that I have tried both the python2.7 and python3.5 `psychopy` install instructions with anaconda as outlined here:
http://psychopy.org/installation.html

Comment: I humbly recommend you post a link to this in the issue tracker of both Pyglet and psychopy. Because it's most likely a integration issue with a formula or w/e you're working on.

Comment: @Torxed thanks, I will post this on the github issues page.

Answer (score 2):

> Another solution given involves ensuring that xf86-video-intel is installed to give a sensible LUT size, I have tried this and it seems that this driver is installed as default on Ubuntu 18, so this does not work for me.

You might need to [set the driver in a configuration file](https://github.com/psychopy/psychopy/issues/2061#issuecomment-428792028). To do this, edit your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file (or create it if it does not exist) to contain the following lines:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately this did not work. I still get the same error.